# Setting cookies with php

Tags: php, setcookie

I have enabled cookies in my browser, but when I run the following PHP, no cookies are being set. The print_r only gives me an empty array.

```
<?php
    echo "My SSL Browser Cookie is set!";

    $name = "SSLCookie"; 
    $value = "1508 - Day 3";
    $expire = time() + (60*60*24*7);

    setcookie($name, $value, $expire);
?>

<pre> 
    <?php 
        print_r($_COOKIE); 
    ?> 
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

worked for me

```
    Array
(
    [_ga] => GA1.1.1962982090.1494253367
    [_gid] => GA1.1.1398313405.1494636302
)
```

[image]

i set cookies something like this

```
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "Bob";
$hostname = "localhost";
setcookie('$cookie_name', $cookie_value, time() + 2678400, '/', $hostname, isset($_SERVER["HTTP"]) , true);
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a cookie after an echo.
Move your echo down after setcookie.